# Decimal value not allowing in my code

Tags: jquery, html

I am new to jquery. I have form with two text boxes. In that i am restrict special characters. But i want allow decimal value.

I implemented decimal code but not working.

```
<form>
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="form-group ">
  <label for="minAmt" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Min.Amount</label>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <input type="text" class="form-control minAmt" id="minAmt" name="minAmt" placeholder="Enter Min Amount" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group ">
  <label for="maxAmt" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Max.Amount</label>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <input type="text" class="form-control maxAmt" id="maxAmt" name="maxAmt" placeholder="Enter Max Amount" />
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Script:

```
$('.minAmt').keyup(function(e){
if($(this).val() == ""){
$('.minAmt').val('');
}else if($(this).val() > 0){
console.log($(this).val());
$(this).val(Number($(this).val()))
}
var character = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)
     var newValue = this.value + character;
     if (isNaN(newValue) || hasDecimalPlace(newValue, 3)) {
         e.preventDefault();
         return false;
     }
});
function hasDecimalPlace(value, x) {
     var pointIndex = value.indexOf('.');
     return  pointIndex >= 0 && pointIndex < value.length - x;
 }
```

What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

The problems here is:

```
var character = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)
     var newValue = this.value + character;
     if (isNaN(newValue) || hasDecimalPlace(newValue, 3)) {
         e.preventDefault();
         return false;
     }
});
```

In this code,

```
var newValue = this.value + character;
```

**it makes some string which is always NaN
therefore it makes isNaN(newValue) = true always.**
and it always true is returned from if block so no "." character visible.

Why you are doing like this. **Better use regex.**

For eg, like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/m5x7n6wr/

And yes, use keypress instead of keyup.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function isNumberKey(evt)
{
 var str = evt.target.value;
 var res = str.match(/^-?\d*\.?\d*$/g);
 if (res == null) {
  var specialChar = str.replace( /[ !@#$%^&*()_\=\[\]{};':"\\|,<>\/?]/gi, '');
  event.target.value = specialChar;
  
  var charc = str.replace(/[^a-z]/gi, '');
  if (charc != "") {
   var end = str.indexOf(charc);
   var replaceVal = str.substring(0,end);
   event.target.value = replaceVal;
  }
  var negIndex = str.lastIndexOf("-");
  if (negIndex > 0) {
   var replaceVal1 = str.substring(0,negIndex);
   event.target.value = replaceVal1;
  }
  
  var posIndex = str.lastIndexOf("+");
  if (posIndex > 0) {
   var replaceVal2 = str.substring(0,posIndex);
   event.target.value = replaceVal2;
  }
  
 }
 
}
```

```html
<form>
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="form-group ">
  <label for="minAmt" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Min.Amount</label>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <input type="text"  onkeyup="return isNumberKey(event)" class="form-control minAmt" id="minAmt" name="minAmt" placeholder="Enter Min Amount" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group ">
  <label for="maxAmt" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Max.Amount</label>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <input type="text"  onkeyup="return isNumberKey(event)" class="form-control maxAmt" id="maxAmt" name="maxAmt" placeholder="Enter Max Amount" />
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: check out this, hope this working as according to you.

Comment: your character code checking does not allow for negative numbers